# How to read YouTube channel?

Tags: iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I have just started developing using Youtube API and stuck in very beginning. I want to know how we can read a channel on Youtube. Means what should I do to read data present on any channel.

Should I use a url and post request on this url.

Or is there any method in the Youtube API calling which i can get the data on a channel.

Please help me folks. I am having no idea from where I should start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To retrieve information about a channel you should be using YouTube's GData API's.
The link below shows the sample request you should be making to search for and retrieve channel information:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search.html

There's also a really nice demo page for these GData calls where you can try out all sorts of requests, check how they are constructed and what they return:
http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

It's all XML based so you'll need to up your DOM/SAX parser skills. :)
Finally, if you are developing in Java, Python or a few other languages, YouTube already provides some implementations for the parsing and requesting here:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/code.html

Comment: Yes, the 2nd link here is very useful, 'though I have struggled to get the .Net api to work at all, so I built my own and talk xml...